# define area-of-disk error?

Tags: racket

In chapter 2.2 of "How to Design Programs" the structure for definitions is given as

```lisp
(define (area-of-disk r) 
  (* 3.14 (* r r)))
```

yet when I enter and evaluate this in DrRacket, it highlights the `(* 3.14 (* r r))` expression, yet no error notification is given.  I've cut and pasted samples from the latest guide, and similar error highlighting results.  I'm running v 5.3.3 of DrRacket on Windows7.

What is the proper structure for the **define** method?

EDIT::  it works after all, I just wasn't clear on why the highlighting was occurring.  It wasn't made clear in the book that the argument would get highlighted upon evaluation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure John Clements's answer is correct here; DrRacket will highlight untested code when it's in Beginner Level mode.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty confident that what you were seeing was the "you haven't evaluated this code" highlighting. This is DrRacket's way of letting you know that you have untested code, and it should go away as soon as you add a test case.

Answer (score 0):

It worked just fine for me. Did you accidentally chop out the `#lang racket` line at the top? If so, put it back and you should be good to go.

Comment: didn't chop the #lang racket line, as I am using the Beginning Student language as prescribed by the book.  I try to be a diligent little student.  Thanks for your advice, I will be on the lookout for that as I progress through the book.